# extend clickable area of element with JQuery alone

Tags: jquery

I have elements that are 15px wide and 15px high and add a class to them when they are clicked or touched as follows:

CSS

```
.light{
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', '.light', function(event){                     
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass("turned-on");
});
```

However I would like to expand/extend the clickable area to 40px wide and high with jquery alone and not touch the CSS, is this possible? I don't want to change the CSS at all, to not change the appearance of the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.width()` and `.height()`:

```
$( this ).width( someValueHere );
$( this ).height( someValueHere );
```

Although note that this does change the CSS behind the scenes. You need to set your width and height in the element's attribute and modify those, in this way you don't change the CSS:

Then do:

```
$( this ).attr( "width","100px" ); // '100px' is just some value
$( this ).attr( "height","100px" );
```

**[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/cL6zf6x0/2/)**

**Notice**: This only works for some elements can are affected by changing their width and height attributes, such as images or canvas. Although for `div` elements they **must** be changes by their CSS (first method), changing the attributes width and height on them is not effective. In that case you must change the CSS, it's not possible otherwise.

Comment: I dont want to change the CSS

Comment: @user1937021 The width and height are defined as a part of the CSS. If you set the height and width as HTML attributes then you can do `.attr('width', ... )`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's what you want, if not, you can improve your question:

HTML(for example):

```
<div class="light"></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', '.light-click', function(event){                     
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".light").addClass("turned-on");
});
$(".light").wrap('<div class="light-click"></div>');
$(".light-click").width("40px").height("40px");
```

JSFIDDLE (I have added a css .light-click class and a background-color to see the result, but you can delete them for your use): http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/nr9excm1/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
.light {
    position:relative;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    z-Index:1;
}
.light:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    left:-12.5px;
    top:-12.5px;
    z-Index:0;
    background:transparent;
}
```

```js
$(document).on("click touchstart", ".light", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass("turned-on");

});
```

```css
.light {
    position:relative;
    left:35%;
    top:50px;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    background : orange;
    z-Index:1;
    border:2px solid blue;
}
.light:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    left:-12.5px;
    top:-12.5px;
    background:transparent;
    z-Index:0;
}
.turned-on {
    background:blue;
    border:2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="light"></div>
```